# onClickListener in Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

Im developing an application which having Images as a Index on selection of particular image that activity will begin but I dont know how to set onClickListener or onTouchListener in Canvas heres my code

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

LinearLayout mLayout;
Bitmap index;
Bitmap book;
Bitmap bird;
Bitmap game;
Bitmap mail;
Bitmap music;
Bitmap torch;
Paint paint;

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);

    index = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.photo1);
    book = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.book);
    game = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.game);
    music = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.music);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    paint = new Paint();
    Bitmap indexcanvas = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(index, canvas.getWidth(),
                                                   canvas.getHeight(), true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(indexcanvas, 0, 0, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(book, 160, 100, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(game, 30, 10, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(music, 80, 50, paint);
} 

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}
```

Please if anyone knows how to add onClickListener for particular image e.g. here if I click on Book then bookActivity will start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try something like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   if((event.getX(0)>=160) && 
      (event.getY(0)>=100) && 
     ( event.getX(0)<=160+BOOK_IMG_WIDTH) && 
      (event.getY(0)<=100+BOOK_IMG_HEIGHT))
      {
          //book selected
      }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Im trying by ur way but I got error "The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, float"...... Please any other option

Comment: Do u have any Idea my requirement is I want to change the Image when the image get clicked so how Im going to change the image for instance and then activity begin..... any logic

Comment: try use [View.invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) method and implement some flag in onDraw to determine which image to draw. And if you want, you can create another question. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageView` instead of bitmap and add it to your layout:

```
book = new ImageView(context);
book.setImageResource(R.drawable.book);
book.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            /*...*/
        }
    };);
```

Comment: I want to set Image in XY co-ordinates.... So I cannot set image in XY co ordinate in ImageResource...

Answer (score 0):

Save the images' coords in an ArrayList. Set OnClickListener on the context, get the point coords that has been clicked, find the image in the arraylist and do something :)

Comment: write but how to update canvas because its inside onDraw() method of view